# writing mp4 file from binary string python

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, binary

I have a Binary string of mp4 video file and want to convert it back to mp4 file, to get single frame out of there with [openCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) library

```
import cv2
import tempfile

temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
video_binary_string = 'AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28yYXZjMW1wNDEAAAAIZnJlZQAQC0ttZGF0AQIUGRQmM...'

with open(temp_path+'/video.mp4', 'wb') as wfile:
   wfile.write(video_binary_string)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(temp_path+'/video.mp4')
success, frame = cap.read()

print success
>>> False
```

If frame was read correctly, it would be **True**

I understand that this is not the correct way of writing video file. I tried to do it with [FFMPEG](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/) but I can't understand it's documentation.

Please give an example with simple explanations how to convert binary string back to video, with this or other way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is that I have to first decode encoded string

```
import cv2
import tempfile
import base64

temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
video_binary_string = 'AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28yYXZjMW1wNDEAAAAIZnJlZQAQC0ttZGF0AQIUGRQmM...'
decoded_string = base64.b64decode(video_binary_string)

with open(temp_path+'/video.mp4', 'wb') as wfile:
   wfile.write(decoded_string)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(temp_path+'/video.mp4')
success, frame = cap.read()

print success
>>> True
```